# PowerBI snowflake connector incorrectly uses ',' as decimal separator

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

When using the SnowFlake connector for PowerBI, the Snowflake sql query is not correctly generated by PowerBI. It is generated with a ',' as decimal separator instead of '.'

I have a snowflake table which contains (among others):

1. Timestamps : `ENQUEUEDTIMEUTC`
2. Beer Temperatures : `BEER_TEMPERATURE`

I try to display the moment corresponding to the highest beer temperature. When more than one moment exists, I want the earliest moment.

**What I do:**

- `card` visualization of `ENQUEUEDTIME`
- Filter on visual : `Top N` filter --> top 1 of `BEER_TEMPERATURE`

**What goes wrong:**

When generating this query, PowerBI incorrectly passes a ',' to represent the value. The query becomes:

```
from "<my warehouse>"."<my schema>"."<my table>"
        where "BEER_TEMPERATURE" = CAST(15,826941 as DOUBLE) ...
```

[image]

This query seems to fail on the ','. It produces the following error message:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 19 at position 42 unexpected
> ','. syntax error line 19 at position 43 unexpected '826941'. syntax
> error line 19 at position 59 unexpected ')'.

The value of 15.83 is the correct value for the beer temperature.

How can I change ',' to '.' in the query PowerBI sends to snowflake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Power BI Desktop go to `File` -> `Options and settings` -> `Options`
Here you have two settings that affect what separator you have, the first is in `CURRENT FILE` -> `Regional Settings`:

[image]

and the second `GLOBAL` -> `Regional Settings`:

[image]

Comment: Solved the problem by setting the Locale for import to `English (United Kingdom)`